# How do I show that for $x,y\in (-1,1) \Rightarrow |x|+|y|-|xy|\in (-1,1)$?

Tags: inequality

As the title says, how do I show that for $x,y\in (-1,1) \Rightarrow |x|+|y|-|xy|\in (-1,1)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $x,y\in (-1,1) $ we have $|x|,|y|< 1$ so

$$E=|x|+|y|-|xy|=1-1 +|x|+|y|-|xy|= 1-(1-|x|)(1-|y|)< 1$$

And since $(1-|xy|)+|x|+|y|>0$ we have $E> -1 $